# Access 2010 WHERE clause not working as expected

Tags: where-clause, ms-access-2010

I have a complex query in Access 2010 where: 
query1 is a query WHERE field1 <> 8 
and 
query2 is the same query WHERE field1=8.

Then I am doing:

```
SELECT * FROM query1 
INNER JOIN query2 ON query1.field2=query2.field2 
WHERE query1.field3=query2.field3
```

This returns 0 results.

However when I change it to:

```
SELECT * from query1 
INNER JOIN query2 ON query1.field2=query2.field2 
WHERE query1.field3=5 AND query2.field3=5
```

I do get results.  Does this make sense to anybody?  Could it have to do with on of the fields being considered a text field?  except it works without quotes so I don't know why that would be.

Please let me know if you have seen this before.

This is the full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT [transactions by category].[categoryid],
           Month([account transactions].[transaction date]) AS TransMonth,
           Year([account transactions].[transaction date])  AS TransYear,
           SUM([transactions by category].[amount])         AS Amount
    FROM   (categories
            INNER JOIN [transactions by category]
                    ON categories.id =
           [transactions by category].categoryid)
           INNER JOIN [account transactions]
                   ON [transactions by category].transactionid =
                      [account transactions].id
    WHERE  [account transactions].[transaction type] <> 8
    GROUP  BY [transactions by category].[categoryid],
              Year([account transactions].[transaction date]),
              Month([account transactions].[transaction date])) AS
   TransactionCredits
   INNER JOIN (SELECT [transactions by category].[categoryid],
                      Month([account transactions].[transaction date]) AS
                                         TransMonth,
                      Year([account transactions].[transaction date])  AS
                      TransYear
                                         ,
                      SUM(
          [transactions by category].[amount])
               FROM   (categories
                       INNER JOIN [transactions by category]
                               ON categories.id =
   [transactions by category].categoryid)
                      INNER JOIN [account transactions]
                              ON [transactions by category].transactionid =
                                 [account transactions].id
               WHERE  [account transactions].[transaction type] = 8
               GROUP  BY [transactions by category].[categoryid],
                         Year([account transactions].[transaction date]),
                         Month([account transactions].[transaction date]))
              AS
                                 TransactionDebits
           ON TransactionCredits.[categoryid] =
              TransactionDebits.[categoryid]
WHERE  TransactionCredits.transyear = TransactionDebits.transyear
   AND TransactionCredits.transmonth = 8
   AND TransactionDebits.transmonth = 8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've been banging my head against the wall for months on this.  I finally found the solution, but I don't fully understand why this works.

Instead of just saying

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM query1 
 INNER JOIN query2 ON query1.field2=query2.field2 
 WHERE query1.field3=query2.field3"
```

I changed the WHERE clause to say

```
VAL(query1.field3)=VAL(query2.field3)
```

Both of these fields were originally integer ID columns but apparently one of them became a text field of some sort somewhere in one of the queries.

I would still be interested in hearing an explanation of how this works.

Thanks

Comment: Val converts a text field to a numeric in your example, which means you do not have a data type mismatch. What did you want explained?

Comment: BTW it is nearly always best to avoid using * to select fields.